# React: prevent sorted table from re-rendering when a row is edited

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table in React that allows sorting and editing rows, which I set up in main component's constructor:

```
this.state = {
    rows: [
          {id: 1, name: 'John Doe', contacts: 'john.doe@gmail.com', rsvp: false, accepted: 0},
          {id: 2, name: 'Jane Doe', contacts: 'jane.doe@gmail.com', rsvp: false, accepted: 1},   
    ], 
    sortBy: {key: null, order: null}  
}
```

It allows sorting (when user clicks on table head it sets sortBy to actual value and order and then pass it through props to the RowList component)

Rows are rendered like so (they are also being passed as a property):

```
//RowList component


let computedRows = rows;    

if(sortBy.key && sortBy.order) {
   computedRows = orderBy(computedRows, [sortBy.key.toLowerCase()], [sortBy.order])
}
   computedRows = computedRows.map((row, index) => 
                     <Row key={index} row={row} index={index} handleChange={handleChange} /> 
                  )
```

So if you set ket to name and order to asc it results in

```
//key = 'name'
//order = 'asc'

Jane Doe (text input) · janedoe@gmail.com (text input)...
John Doe (text input)· johndoe@gmail.com (text input)...
```

Row itself is a bunch of inputs that allows to edit info in the state, e.g. if you change name it will update the name to Zohn Doe in will update it in the state and *switch the rows and re-render the table while user is still typing...*

I've tried returning `false` in `shouldComponentUpdate()`. It prevents from row switching but also doesn't allow to change values in the inputs.

How would I retain ability to edit inputs, but not to change order?

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `row`'s `id` property as the key, and also update the state based on the `id`, React won't unmount the input elements, and you can continue typing even when the array reordered.

That might not be an ideal user experience though, so you could also create a custom input component that keeps track of its own input state and only propagates changes on blur (i.e. when it loses focus):

```
class DeferredInput extends Component {
  state = { value: this.props.value };

  componentWillReceiveProps({value}) {
    if (value !== this.state.value) {
      this.setState({value});
    }
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({value: event.currentTarget.value});
  }

  handleBlur = () => {
    this.props.onBlur(this.state.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input type='text' value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} onBlur={this.handleBlur}/>
    );
  }
}
```

Use it like this: `<DeferredInput value={..} onBlur={..}/>`.

Comment: Thanks, it a valuable improvement, though sorting still occurs after the blur – what I'd like to prevent